# Field data as part of external URL call (jsonclient plugin)

Tags: templating, plugins, url, json

It's possible it's the various search terms I'm using but I can't seem to find anything close to what I'm looking for.

I am trying to call an external API URL, with keywords from a field, but while I can 'form' the URL outside of the code, inside it breaks.

This is the idea of what I'm trying, based on the plugin's example code...

````
 {# Get a random Fact form chucknorris.io #}
    {% set jsonData = fetchJson({
      'url': 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes&keyword={{ field.name }}&apikey=12345'
    }) %}

    {% if (jsonData) %}
      <h1>Fact of the day</h1>
      {{ jsonData.value }}
    {% endif %}
    ```
I don't find a lot of code particularly friendly, so the idea of having a plugin that 'intepreted' it was super exciting - just while it'll pull the URL fine if I type a term in, obviously the brackets are breaking it!
````

Answer (score 1):

As you found, you're not allowed to nest Twig delimiters. But you don't need to - once inside a Twig statement/block/variable/object/whatever, you can use any Twig variables without delimiters like this using the [concatenation operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators) `~`:

```
{% set jsonData = fetchJson({
      'url': 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes&keyword=' ~ field.name ~ '&apikey=12345'
}) %}
```

Or if you prefer you can use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) (note this *requires* double quote marks):

```
{% set jsonData = fetchJson({
      'url': "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes&keyword=#{field.name}&apikey=12345"
}) %}
```